# How to get some of the codepoint emoji values to work

Tags: javascript, html

[image]For example: "rolling on the floor laughing" gives a square in the browser. How do I get the actual emoji to show up not like a suqare?

`String.fromCodePoint(0x1F923)`

Here is a pic of arups jsbin that shows up like this:
[image]

Comment: I can't get it to show up like a square. Try providing a [mcve]. What are you doing with the return value from that function? Where are you trying to render it?

Comment: I see it [working](https://jsbin.com/lanejohogo/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In you `<head>` tag, did you add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` ?

Comment: @Arup I'm having issues. it doesn't show up in mu browser. @Fcmam added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Provide that HTML/JS code snippet, maybe a screenshot will help, The issue might be with your browser, or the fonts you are using.

Comment: Fcmam5 I'm trying only console.log it in my browser. Arups working example is showing as a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is working for me on Firefox 61. The output is:

[image]

And on Google Chrome I'm having:

[image]

Now, try running this code snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('.output').textContent = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F923);

console.log(String.fromCodePoint(0x1F923));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class='output'></p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you still getting that square, please check your browser's encoding & your default fonts. And check if it supports emojis, like on my Google Chrome didn't render it.

So maybe you need to use a third-party JavaScript library like [Twitter's Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji):

```js
// I got the Unicode for that emoji(1F602) from www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html
document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = twemoji.convert.fromCodePoint('1F602');
```

```html
<script src="//twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/twemoji.min.js?11.0"></script>

<p class="output"></p>
```